# Unable to upload files in upload folder using php on localhost due to restriction on permission change imposed by Windows 7

Tags: php, windows-7, file-upload, permissions, localhost

I am doing File upload using PHP, files are unable to get uploaded because the folder is set to read-only. I have installed **XAMPP** and in my *htdocs* folder there is a folder whom i want to make my upload folder.

After searching from a long time, i finally came up to Microsoft Support Forum, it said that we cannot change folder permission.

Check this out @ Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549

Still if anyone have any solution to it...

I tried `chmod("upload/", 0777);` for upload folder before file uploading process, still its not working...

I am adding my script also, so that you people can find a pass through for me.

```
$exten = explode( "." , $_FILES['complaint_file']['name']);
    $exten = $exten[1];
    if ( ($exten == "jpg") || ($exten == "JPG") || ($exten == "jpeg") || ($exten == "JPEG") || ($exten == "png") || ($exten == "PNG") || ($exten == "gif") || ($exten == "GIF") )
    {
        chmod("upload/", 0777);
        if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['complaint_file']['temp_name'], "upload/".time().".".$exten))
        {
            $filename = time().".".$exten;
            $insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE complaints SET complaint_status='CLOSED', complaint_solved_date=NOW(), complaint_remark=%s complaint_filename=%s WHERE complaint_number=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['complaint_remark'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['confirm_close_complaint'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($filename, "text"));
            $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dacreint) or die(mysql_error());  
            header('Location: complaint-register.php?ComplaintClose=Successful');
            exit();
        }
        else {
            header('Location: complaint-register.php?FileUploadError=1');
            exit();
        }
    }
    else {
        header('Location: complaint-register.php?ExtensionError=1');
        exit();
    }
```

When i do file upload it skips the if condition and runs the following piece of code from top:-

```
else {
        header('Location: complaint-register.php?FileUploadError=1');
        exit();
    }
```